# starting Rails app on alternate port using Guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard

I'm using Guard, and there doesn't seem to be a way to specify an alternate port than default 3000. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [guard-rails](https://github.com/johnbintz/guard-rails)

```
guard 'rails', :port => 5000 do
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch(%r{^(config|lib)/.*})
end
```